# Getting Parameters from a Hashtag Url

Tags: jquery, url, hashtag

I am trying to get the id from an url that looks like this '#somepage?id=5' the function I am using for this doesn't seem to work the function in question is:

```
function getParam(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
if (results == null)
    return "";
else
    return results[1];
}
```

is there a way I can modify or replace this function to pull the id from a url as stated above?

Comment: Little bit of debugging shows it working if you pass in the hash: http://jsfiddle.net/KbmU8/ most likely `window.location.href` isn't giving you what you want.

Comment: Try using `location.hash`

Comment: `location.hash` doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: I just tried it, it works with `location.hash`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

[Javascript code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Note however that your snippet will have the same issue as the OP. the data is stored in the Hash, not the querystring.